# hot to play Hd videos in multiple monitors

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, macos, video, air

I'm looking for a solution to play HD videos on a multimonitor OSX environment for a projector/desktop application. It could be one huge video, or a video split in parts.

So far I've been using Flash StageVideo successfully to play 1080p and 720p on single monitors. This works great with flash projectors. The problem with flash projectors is you can't span multiple monitors, or multiple windows. I still haven't tried opening multiple projectors, because I wouldn't know how to position each projector in a different monitor consistently.

In Adobe AIR you can have multiple windows and control their position, but AFAIK you can't use StageVideo to decode videos with the GPU... and using the classic Video class is really out of the question.

With C++ there are multiple frameworks (cinder/openFrameworks) but AFAIK opening multiple windows, or spaning multiple monitors is not such a good idea because of bad performance. I stil haven't figured out if it's possible or even a good idea to open one app per monitor and control it's position.

Has anyone succeeded in this problem using AS3 or any other language/framework like C++ with openFrameworks?

Comment: What is the question and how is it programming related?

Comment: The question is a the end of my post. It's obviously related to programming because the solution involves coding.

Answer (score 1):

With AIR you can have a single window span multiple windows.

I have a 1920x1080 video scaled by 2 on stage of 3840x2160. I haven't yet tried using StageVideo to up the resolution, but I am hopeful it will work.

Comment: You mean you have a window air span 2 monitors? But then you can't use StageVideo in AIR for desktop, can you?

Comment: oh I didn't realise that! its really annoying that stageVideo is unavailable in AIR. But yes I did mean having an AIR window span two monitors

Comment: But can you have that window over the system menu bar?

Comment: Yeah sure - set the width, height, x, y as you like

Comment: I tried that in Mac OS Lion and it didn't work. The system bar was always over the adobe air window. Anyway the video performance without stageVideo is useless for HD videos. Thanks.